# Create schedule job SQL Datawarehouse

Tags: azure-synapse

We are using polybase to load data from azure blob storage to Sql Datawarehous. How do we scheduling job  so that that that can be updated regularly without manual effort?

Comment: Azure Data Factory?  Please provide some more detail on the scheduling and job requirements.

Answer (score 4):

What I normally do is, I use the Job Agent on one of my on premise or Azure based SQL Box installations to schedule the execution of stored procedures in either an APS or ADW.

Alternatively if you are looking at a fully end to end PASS solution, I would say look at Azure Data Factory.

You can look at this article for an example how to use ADF : 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/data-factory-stored-proc-activity/